# Where is the reference documentation on the Kibana query language?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I have been searching on google for this multiple times and always give up.  Here is the best thing I've been able to find on the topic: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/queries.html

This is lacking.  For example, how do I search for strings that "start with" a string. Or, "end width"?  Or how do I use a regex?  etc.  I don't want these questions directly answered, I just want a link to the documentation that answers these things.

I am using Kibana 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#search

And if you check the request that Kibana does you will see that it actually uses [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with `analyze_wildcard:true` option when you search something. So you can check documentation for Query String Query for abilities.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This seems like a more direct link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax  Though I find this pretty lacking.  It doesn't mention if it searches full words, partial, starts with, ends with by default, nor how to do these things.  No examples of regexes, either.

Comment: +1 this is a 'quick start guide' but is definitely not a reference. For something so key in the user experience I'd expect a full guide. Disappointed that one doesn't seem to exist.